# How to extract just the .hfs partition from a dmg file

Tags: partitioning, apple, extract, hfs+

I have a macOS dmg file.. `BaseSystem.dmg`. It is compressed and contains various hfs partitions..

```
# file BaseSystem.dmg 
BaseSystem.dmg: zlib compressed data
```

**What I want to do**
I want to extract just the `4.hfs` partition file. But I cannot.
This is possible on Windows using the [Boot Disk Utility](http://cvad-mac.narod.ru/index/bootdiskutility_exe/0-5) tool as [demonstrated here](https://youtu.be/fqK-dUdChwE?t=486).

**Here is what I tried**
If I use dmg2img like this...

```
flex@flex-ubuntu:~/Documents/MacOS$ dmg2img BaseSystem.dmg 

dmg2img v1.6.7 (c) vu1tur (to@vu1tur.eu.org)

BaseSystem.dmg --> BaseSystem.img


decompressing:
opening partition 0 ...             100.00%  ok
opening partition 1 ...             100.00%  ok
opening partition 2 ...             100.00%  ok
opening partition 3 ...             100.00%  ok
opening partition 4 ...             100.00%  ok
opening partition 5 ...             100.00%  ok
opening partition 6 ...             100.00%  ok
opening partition 7 ...             100.00%  ok

Archive successfully decompressed as BaseSystem.img
```

If I now try to mount `BaseSystem.img`..

```
$ sudo mount -o loop -t hfsplus BaseSystem.img /mnt/macimage
mount: /mnt/macimage: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop7, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

So that command does not mount it. This commands returns a single loopback device:
`# sudo losetup -P -f --show BaseSystem.img`
Which I CAN mount like this:
`# sudo mount /dev/loop8p1 /mnt/macimage/`

But what I want is to just extract the 4.hfs partition file?!

If I look at the properties of `BaseSystem.img`...

```
# file BaseSystem.img
BaseSystem.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 1, 4176871 sectors, extended partition table (last)
```

From Ubuntu Terminal:
`# 7z l BaseSystem.dmg` I get...

```
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 498625205 bytes (476 MiB)

Listing archive: BaseSystem.dmg

--
Path = BaseSystem.dmg
Type = Dmg
Physical Size = 498625205
Method = Copy Zero2 ZLIB CRC
Blocks = 594
----
Path = 4.hfs
Size = 2004299776
Packed Size = 498579443
Comment = disk image (Apple_HFS : 4)
Method = Copy Zero2 ZLIB CRC
--
Path = 4.hfs
Type = HFS
Physical Size = 2004299776
Method = HFS+
Cluster Size = 4096
Free Space = 678445056
Created = 2020-10-30 08:13:26
Modified = 2020-10-30 16:31:38
```

How can I extract **just** the file `4.hfs`?

When I run this command:
`# 7z x BaseSystem.dmg` it extracts the entire dmg file to give a directory tree of all the files in the dmg file. But I only want to extract a single file out of the dmg file: `4.hfs`.

If I run this command: `7z x BaseSystem.dmg 4.hfs` I get...

```
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,8 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 498625205 bytes (476 MiB)

Extracting archive: BaseSystem.dmg
--            
Path = BaseSystem.dmg
Type = Dmg
Physical Size = 498625205
Method = Copy Zero2 ZLIB CRC
Blocks = 594
----
Path = 4.hfs
Size = 2004299776
Packed Size = 498579443
Comment = disk image (Apple_HFS : 4)
Method = Copy Zero2 ZLIB CRC
--
Path = 4.hfs
Type = HFS
Physical Size = 2004299776
Method = HFS+
Cluster Size = 4096
Free Space = 678445056
Created = 2020-10-30 08:13:26
Modified = 2020-10-30 16:31:38


No files to process
Everything is Ok

Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 498625205
```

But then nothing is output in the folder where I would expect `4.hfs` to appear.

What am I doing wrong?  Is it maybe not possible on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I found that `dmg2img` and `7z` can both extract just a partition from a `dmg` file.

Using `dmg2img` we can see the contents of the dmg file:

```
# dmg2img -l BaseSystem.dmg 

dmg2img v1.6.7 (c) vu1tur (to@vu1tur.eu.org)

BaseSystem.dmg --> (partition list)

partition 0: Protective Master Boot Record (MBR : 0)
partition 1: GPT Header (Primary GPT Header : 1)
partition 2: GPT Partition Data (Primary GPT Table : 2)
partition 3:  (Apple_Free : 3)
partition 4: disk image (Apple_HFS : 4)
partition 5:  (Apple_Free : 5)
partition 6: GPT Partition Data (Backup GPT Table : 6)
partition 7: GPT Header (Backup GPT Header : 7)
```

### Using dmg2img v1.6.7

This command extracts the `4.hfs` partition:

```
# dmg2img -p 4 -i BaseSystem.dmg -o 4.hfs
```

### Using 7z

In 7-Zip [64] 9.20 you can use this command:

```
7z e BaseSystem.dmg 4.hfs
```

In 7-Zip [64] 16.02 you need to use this command:

```
7z e -t* BaseSystem.dmg 4.hfs
```

The `-t*` is needed or else in this version of 7z it will not extract to just one level deep but instead it will extract everything down to files and folders.